# How to change Entity Framework EDMX connection string dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to read the connection string from a `.txt` file that I created before. I tried passing the connection string variable to `DbContext` constructor as a string variable that I created manually but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it in your Context constructor

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Path to your text File");
    }
}
```